# General Knowledge: Assembling Sprite Sheets Programmatically?

Tags: graphics, game-engine, photoshop, photoshop-script

Currently, my sprite sheets are drawn in photoshop, exported as a .png, then manually divided into an xml file for the texture loader to process (string id, x, y, width, height.)

Is there a way to write a script to output spritesheet metadata instead of doing it by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already had a look at [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to script Photoshop grabbing a folder of images and then place them into a sprite sheet and then kick out the sprite meta data. But [texture packer](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/features) already does the job you want.